# Calling a RESTful Web Service from Kendo Grid

Tags: web-services, rest, kendo-ui

I'm using this snippet in my Kendo grid :

```
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://localhost/myService",
                    dataType: "json"
                },                        
                parameterMap: function () {
                    return {
                        param1: 1,
                        param2: 2
                    };
                }
            }
        }
```

This will send the web request as `"http://localhost/myService?param1=1&param2=2"`. However, my RESTful web service expects something like `"http://localhost/myService/1/2"`. What should I do to format the correct HTTP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DataSource instead of defining it as a String, define it as function:

```
dataSource: {
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: function (data) {
                return "http://localhost/myService/1/2";
            }
        }
    }
```